# Can one "manually override" BibTeX's choice of citation keys by adding a field to the entry?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Normally, I'm basically OK with BibTeX's choice of citation key (by which I mean, the short symbol it shows in the final document, like [2] or [Hil05], not the one one types in the tex file), but every once in a while there's a paper that cries out for a particular key (such as the paper of Freyd, Hoste, Lickorish, Millet, Ocneano and Yetter in which the HOMFLY polynomial is defined clearly should have the key [HOMFLY], not [FHL+95]), or BibTeX picks a particularly bad one.

*In these cases, is there a field one can insert into the bibtex entry to override the key choice, or something one can do other than editing the .bbl file?*

Answer (score 38):

Using [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), you may add the `shorthand` field:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  shorthand = {Author},
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
@misc{B02,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Bravo},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

If you use the [`natbib`](http://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) package, you can declare an "alias" or alternative citation for a source:

For example, the following `.bib` entry:

```
@techreport{caltrans2002,
    Author = {{California Department of Transportation}},
    Title = {{Humboldt Bay Bridges Seismic Substructure Retrofit Environmental  Assessment/Finding of No Significant Impact (EA/FONSI)}},
    Year = {2002}}
```

Produces the following output when `\citep{caltrans2002}` used in a document:

---

[image: Example citation without alias.]

---

Having a citation that spans most of a line can be pretty bothersome- especially when the full name has to appear in the bibliography but there is a nice shorthand that should be used when citing in the text. By including `\usepackage{natbib}` in your preamble, you have access to citation aliases:

```
\defcitealias{caltrans2002}{\scshape CalTrans, 2002}
```

Then using `\citepalias{caltrans2002}` instead of `\citep{caltrans2002}` produces the following output:

---

[image: Example citation using an alias.]

---

In both cases, the associated entry in the bibliography looks like this:

---

[image: Example bibliography text.]

---

The LaTeX and BibTeX source I used to create this example can be obtained from [GitHub](http://gist.github.com/491290).

Comment: Is there a way to use an alias w/multiple citations, i.e., in a situation where one would use `\citep[][]{key1,key2,...,keyN`?

Answer (score 9):

There's actually a pretty good answer over at Stack Overflow: [Is there a way to override a bibtex style file for a particular entry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982075/is-there-a-way-to-override-a-bibtex-style-file-for-a-particular-entry).

The fact that the programming language BibTeX style files (.bst) are written in is called BAFLL may alert you to the fact that this sort of problem is a pain to deal with.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can modify your `.bbl` file by hand. You could even use `sed` to automatically make the desired change after each time you regenerate the `.bbl` file using BibTeX --- I can show you the details if you like (ask a new question?).

Comment: Just edit the `sed`-fu into this answer.

Comment: I don't see how this is possible; a `bibtex` produced `.bbl` file contains nothing at all about (shorthand) cite labels; see e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154215/biblatex-biber-to-bibitem/199642#199642 ... if you meant changes in the `.bst`, that is something else altogether.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a really hacky solution, if one just needs to change maybe one or two labels and wants to stick with `bibtex` and avoid editing the `bst` file.

The only changes are in the `.bib` file, where we add two macros.

```
@preamble{"\newcommand\HOlabel{}"}
@preamble{"\newcommand\HO[2]{HOMFLY}"}
@article{HOMFLY,
  author  = {\HOlabel{P.~Freyd, D.~Yetter, J.~Hoste, W.~B.~R.~Lickorish, K.~Millett, and A.~Ocneanu}},
  title   = {{A new polynomial invariant of knots and links}},
  journal = {Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.)},
  volume  = {12},
  Year    = {1985}
}
```

The entry in the generated `bbl` file will look like

```
\bibitem[\HO85]{HOMFLY}
\HOlabel{P.~Freyd, D.~Yetter, J.~Hoste, W.~B.~R.~Lickorish, K.~Millett, and A.~Ocneanu}.
\newblock {A new polynomial invariant of knots and links}.
\newblock {\em Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. (N.S.)}, 12, 1985.
```

The first macro tricks `bibtex` into thinking that `\HO` is the first three letters of author's name, so the label becomes `\HO85`. Then the second macro eats the two digits and outputs the desired label.

Also, this entry will be sorted as `HO` (i.e., it will appear under the letter `H` instead of `F`)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid using `natbib` and `biblatex` (sometimes I have compilation issues with these packages), you can simple use the [abstract](http://ftp.isu.edu.tw/pub/Unix/CTAN/biblio/bibtex/contrib/abstract.bst) style, as it uses they bibtex keys as cite keys. This was pointed out by this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290239/79812).

---

Alternatively, this is also addressed by this [alternative_answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98693/79812), however it involves more steps:

1) download this style: http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bibtex/alpha.bst

2) place it in your project's directory, preferentially under a different name (e.g. `keystyle.bst`).

3) in the file, replace the `output.bibitem` entry to:

```
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem[" write$
   cite$ write$
%  label write$
  "]{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

This answer

Comment: With `biblatex` you use no `bst` file. Can you add an MWE please (best!) or explain with own words how that should work?

Comment: I know that biblatex does not use bst file. The solution that I presented is for NOT using biblatex nor natbib. Maybe I should edit the answer to make it more clear. Do you wish a MWE for the proposed solution?

Answer (score 1):

I also had to avoid `natbib` and `biblatex` as I was already given a template which had `thesis_style.bst` by Patrick W. Daly based on `alpha.bst`.

It already had support for the `key` field in bibtex entries, but the `key` was used as citation label only in case `author` was empty. I modified the following code

```
FUNCTION {author.key.label}
{ key empty$
    { author empty$
        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
        { author format.lab.names }
      if$
    }
    { key #3 text.prefix$ }
  if$
}
%{ author empty$
%    { key empty$
%        { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
%        { key #3 text.prefix$ }
%      if$
%    }
%    { author format.lab.names }
%  if$
%}
```

which makes it first prefer the key field and only then the author.