# Use BibTeX key as the cite key

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, citing

I tried to use `natbib` and other attempts but for vain. I would like to produce a cite key which is identical to the BibTeX entry. For example, if I have a BibTeX entry `Bt98`, then I want `\cite{Bt98}` to produce something like `[Bt98]`.

Any ideas how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Should be easy to realize. Do you need the package `natbib` anyway?

Comment: @Herbert: At the moment I don't need `natbib`, I just tried to use it in order to produce the desired result. I'd be happy to do it without it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a `biblatex` solution with a properly formatted bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=debug]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\thefield{entrykey}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{whatever,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Testing the effects of biblatex styles on bibliography formatting},
}
@misc{B02f,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {First},
}
@misc{B02s,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Second},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This seems like the solution for my setting. One remark though, I was not familiar with the package `filecontents`, and it made your answer unclear at first sight.

Comment: @Dror: I'm sorry I didn't bother to explain `filecontents`.

Comment: No worries! At first it made me insert a lengthy edit to my original question, but then somehow I figured it out. So now it seems OK. I have to admit, I thought the solution would be simpler. Some sort of predefined style.

Comment: If you're starting from `bibtex`, you still do this using `biblatex` by adding `backend=bibtex` in the arguments to `\usepackage{biblatex}`.  If you're relying on `natbib` as well, the only way I could get the list of refs I needed was to take a copy of my source and strip all the natbib stuff, replacing it with biblatex as above.

Answer (score 3):

`biblatex` with, for example, the `style=draft` option will do this.

Comment: has also an effect to the bibliography

Comment: +1 for pointing me to `sorting=debug`.

Answer (score 3):

Without natbib, I don't know if it should be the same in the bibliography?

```
\documentclass{article}


\makeatletter
\def\@citex[#1]#2{\leavevmode
  \if@filesw\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{#2}}\fi
  \@cite{#2}{#1}}
\makeatother


\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{whatever,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Testing the effects of biblatex styles on bibliography formatting},
}

@misc{B02f,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {First},
}

@misc{B02s,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Second},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}

foo\cite{whatever} and bar\cite{B02s}

\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{\jobname}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your changes affect the in-text-citation labels, but not the labels and the sorting order in the bibliography.

Comment: @lockstop: I know, otherwise I hadn't ask if it should be ion the bib too ... ;-) And the question was to change `\cite` ...

Answer (score 2):

If you are having trouble with `natbib` and `biblatex` (sometimes I have compilation issues with these packages), the following [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/98693/79812) enables you to avoid those packages. Only three simple steps:

1) download this style: http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/bibtex/alpha.bst

2) place it in your project's directory, preferentially under a different name (e.g. `keystyle.bst`).

3) in the file, replace the `output.bibitem` entry to:

```
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem[" write$
   cite$ write$
%  label write$
  "]{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

Comment: One should *not* use `natbib` and `biblatex` in one and the same document. Did you maybe mean to write `BibTeX` rather than `biblatex`?

Comment: I edited the answer to clarify that this is an alternative to use BibTeX key as the cite key, WITHOUT using the natbib and biblatex packages. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The `abstract` bibtex style does so out of the box.