# LaTeX Bibliography / Citation Style Basic Question

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, citing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use BiBTeX key as the cite key](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8428/use-bibtex-key-as-the-cite-key)

Let's say I have a .bib file where I'm citing a paper, say:

```
@ARTICLE{Bob04,
 author={B.B. Bobs},
 title={Bob's Theory},
 journal={bob-ph/0102137},
 year={2004},
}
```

Now, in my main document say I want to cite this reference, but using \cite{Bob04}. What I want, is the citation to reflect what is typed after the @ symbol

```
@ARTICLE{Bob04 ...
```

So for instance I would like

```
In Bob's paper[Bob04]
```

Is there any existing bib style or way to override to allow this to happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at the `alpha` bibliography style? It is set to create a citation's "label" automatically from the first three letters of the (first) author's surname and the last two numerals of the publication year. I.e., `\cite{Bob04}` will generate a label that looks like this: `[Bob04]`. In general, I'd say it's preferable to let BibTeX (or biblatex) do the tedious work of creating labels in a consistent manner; no need to restrict the author (i.e., you) to create keys for the entries that conform to the `alpha` (or similar) bibliography style.

Comment: I'd have to agree with you, but for the particular purpose of the document, it would be best to have a custom ability to choose how to represent the cited reference. Any specific way to accomplish this in bibtex? Thanks again Mico.

Comment: This will be in the official release of biblatex 2.0/biber 1.0