# Sort bibliography with the order of appearance into .bib file (EDITED)

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, sorting

I work with `natbib` and `\bibliographystyle{abstract}`. I use this style because the ordering is done with respect to the key. Is it possible achieve a sorting with respect the order of appearance into the associated .bib file but without modifying anything other? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I found this answer in the question here

[Use BibTeX key as the cite key](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8428/use-bibtex-key-as-the-cite-key)

relevant

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic,sorting=debug]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\thefield{entrykey}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{whatever,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Testing the effects of biblatex styles on bibliography formatting},
}
@misc{B02f,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {First},
}
@misc{B02s,
  author = {Buthor, B.},
  year = {2002},
  title = {Second},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

So basically how could I achieve the bibliography sorting with respect to the order of appearance in the bib file using `natbib` and `\bibliographystyle{abstract}`(so that a key of the form [CINV] comes before a key of the form [CINT])?

Comment: The term "order of appearance" is slightly ambiguous: Do you mean order of first citation in the body of the document, or order of appearance in the bib file?

Comment: @Mico Sorry for not being clear. The latter one (in bib file!).

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)][https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)  that show how you use the commands you describe in your question?

Comment: The `abstract` bibliography style does not seem to cooperate well with the `natbib` package. (`Package natbib Error: Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.`)

Comment: @leandriis - The OP has (probably) figured out by now that the `natbib` citation management package needs to be loaded with the option `numbers`.