# How to cite an Organization as author?

Tags: bibtex, citing

Ok, first of all, that's not that case that it just have to put double brackets. I have to cite a Standard using it's name, like `ISO 3889 (2017)`, for example. But in Brazil, at References session, for standards the authors name has to be, in that example `INTERNATIONAL ORGANIZATION FOR STANDARDIZATION` (so it appears first). When I use `\cite{iso3889}`, for that example, the entire name appears. If I could cite the field `Organization` of bibtex, I could write `ISO 3889` on this field, to cite directly, but I don't know how. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Since you are using bibtex, look at `key`.  This question may help: [Use BibTeX key as the cite key](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8428/579).

Comment: I'd avise you to take at the `abntex2-cite` package documentation. There you'll find examples for that (and plenty of other situations).