# Defining keys (links) for quotations

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to adapt keys to my bibliography section, but Latex still generates its own ones.

My main file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, abstract=on, fleqn]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrhack}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cite}
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\usepackage[justification=justified,singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

This is a quote: 'bla bla!' from \cite{VDI2607}
\bibliography{literature} 
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\end{document}
```

literature.bib:

```
@Book{VDI2607,
author    = {Lamport, Leslie},
title     = {\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System},
year      = {1994},
isbn      = {0-021-52983-1},
publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
```

}

I want the link to my source to appear exactly as I defined it in key (VDI2607), but Latex still displays it as [Ing00]

How can I solve this?
I want to freely define a key!

Comment: According to the bibtex manual key is used to generate a label when the author is not present.

Comment: How can I define my own key even though an author is listed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

copy the file `alpha.bst` to `myalpha.bst` and modify the function `output.bibitem` to

```
FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem[" write$
   cite$ write$
%  label write$
  "]{" write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}
```

for a test put the file `myalpha.bst` into your documents directory. Then you'll get the key as label:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{myrefs.bib}

@Book{VDI2607,
    author    = {Lamport, Leslie},
    title     = {\LaTeX: A Document Preparation System},
    year      = {1994},
    isbn      = {0-021-52983-1},
    publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

This is a quote: 'bla bla!' from \cite{VDI2607}

\bibliographystyle{myalpha}
\bibliography{myrefs} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. Just one follow-up question: How can I turn the citation into a link, i.e. make it clickable?

Comment: use package `hyperref`

Comment: How can the entry keys be ordered alphabetically in the reference list?

Comment: the sorting is done by `bibtex` or `biber`

Comment: How can apply bibtex here? All my source entries are in a file \begin{filecontents}{myrefs.bib}
...
\end{filecontents}, I am using \bibliography{literature}
\bibliographystyle{myalpha} for my bibliography

Comment: then it is not possible and you have to do it manually.

Comment: How can I do it manually?

Comment: ?? copy and paste, or I didn't understand your problem.

Comment: The references are listed in my bibliography, but they are not sorted propperly. I want the entries in the bibiography to be ordered by their keys. For example, "A_reference" has to be listed before "B_reference"

Comment: I wrote nonsense. Thought that you were using `\begin{thebibliography}...`. However, what style is `myalpha`. The default style `alpha` does the sorting by default.

Comment: You defined myalpha above in your answer ;-)
It works fine but unfortunately lacks the alphabetical ordering

Comment: I looked into the style file and there is no easy solution. However, you can run bibtex which creates a file `<file>.bbl`. You can modify this one and replace the `\bibliography{myrefs}` with `\input{<file>.bbl}`

Comment: Editing the <file>.bbl seems pointless as it gets immediately overwritten once I build my report, so the "order" is reverted, there is still chaos

Comment: then rename it to `bib.tex` and it will be fine.