# Can one “manually override” BibTeX's choice of citation keys by adding a field to the entry? II

Tags: bibtex

There a previous question on this subject [Can one "manually override" BibTeX's choice of citation keys by adding a field to the entry?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102/can-one-manually-override-bibtexs-choice-of-citation-keys-by-adding-a-field-t)

Let me recall it. There are sometimes one wants to edit BibTex's choice  of citation key. For example, for a paper by Freyd, Hoste, Lickorish, Millet, Ocneano and Yetter someone may want to cite [HOMFLY] instead of [FHL+95]. This was solved in above's question by the command

`shorthand = {NewLabel}`

so that the cite is labelled as [NewLabel].

My problem is getting this on a concrete example. I am using `\bibliographystyle{amsalpha}` and I am writing

```
@book{SGA6,
 shorthand = {SGA6},
 title = {Th\'eorie des intersections et th\'eor\`eme de {R}iemann-{R}och},
 series = {Lecture Notes in Mathematics},
 volume  = "225",
 note = {S{\'e}minaire de G{\'e}om{\'e}trie Alg{\'e}brique du Bois-Marie 1966--1967 (SGA 6)},
 publisher = {Springer-Verlag, Berlin-New York},
 year = {1971},
}
```

However, I am getting[image] instead of [SGA6] and I don't know why.

*Does anyone know how to solve this?*

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: In the question you quoted, the `shorthand` field solution is for use with **biblatex**, and not bibtex.

Comment: Thank you Willie Wong and others for pointing out the duplicate. Before closing and erasing this question. I think that the good solution is then to switch to Biblatex and not remain with just bibtex (which I don't have any reason for that). I included the code `\usepackage{biblatex}` but then it gives me the error `Command \bibhand already defined`. I have searched on the web but I don't know how to solve it. By the way, I am using `\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}` in case it is the source of the problem

Comment: you should ask that as a separate question! Many people who can answer your follow-up question will not see it if you put it as a comment to a closed question.