# How to suppress minus in bibtex reference for company author with a minus?

Tags: bibtex, author

I had a "company author" in bibtex like `author = {X-Rite, Inc.}`.
Unfortunately the author was output as `Inc., X-Rite` with a reference like `XR05` (using `\bibliographystyle{alpha}`).
So I changed the author to `author = {{X-Rite, Inc.}}`.
Now the author comes out as `X-Rite, Inc.`, but the reference became `X-R05`.

Can I avoid the minus in the reference in an easy way? I'm using LaTeX...

Comment: Maybe one of the solutions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102/63847) will allow you to override the abbreviation to `XR05`, avoiding the hyphen?

Comment: `shorthand = {XR}` you mean?

Comment: Sure. That post has several different suggestions; `shorthand` is one of them (but requires `biblatex`).